# How to switch between SAML at OAuth2 at runtime (using Spring Security)?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

I am currently writing a Spring Boot 2.x application that by default is authenticated by the app's oauth2 authorization server. However, I would like to add support such as the user could configure the app to use their SAML identity provider/asserting party (like Active Directory) as an alternative to the default OAuth2 authentication server.

What I can see is that developers would write a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with `.saml2Login()` or `.oauth2ResourceServer(o -> o.jwt())` but I would switch between the two at runtime.

Note that I will secure the same set of URLs/APIs. It's just that I want the user to be able to choose what to use. Also as a disclaimer, I do not have experience with SAML.

Would this be possible to do in Spring Boot? Hope someone could say definitively if this is possible or not.

Comment: I am also facing same challenge now. @Robby, have you figured out how it should be done?

Comment: Not yet because we have postponed the feature indefinitely and no one in SO seems to know the answer.